# Wordpress - Category image

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I know this question was asked so many times, but none of the solutions are working for me.
I want to display my categories on the website with their thumbnails together.

I tried to use category imagies plugin, but for some reason this plugin stopped working and doesn't give me the opportunity to attach picture to the category (the add image button isn't shown in the category settings).

After this I created custom field, where I made a taxonomy is equal to category. With this I could pair images with categories, but I don't know how to add it to the code.

Here is my code:

```
<section id="categories">
    <div class="center-box">
        <div class="categories">
            <?php 
            $categories = get_categories(array ('parent' => 0));
            foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
            <div class="category-box">
                <a class="category-img" href="<?php echo get_category_link($category->term_id); ?>">
                    <img class="img" src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($category->term_id); ?>"/>
                    <div class="category-name">
                    <h3> <?php  echo $category->name; ?> </h3>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        
        <?php
        $args = array(
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'orderby' => 'date', 
        'order' => 'DESC', 
        'category' => $category->term_id, );
        ?>
        
            <?php   } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

It still has the previous category imagies plugin code which doesn't work anymore.

Someone could help me how to display the categories with image?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin for this, if you are not already. Under the working assumption that you are, you could do the following:

```
<section id="categories">
<div class="center-box">
    <div class="categories">
        <?php 
        $categories = get_categories(array ('parent' => 0));
        foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
        <div class="category-box">
            <a class="category-img" href="<?php echo get_category_link($category->term_id); ?>">
                <img class="img" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_field( 'thumbnail', "term_$category->term_id" ), 'small' ) ?>"/>
                <div class="category-name">
                <h3> <?php  echo $category->name; ?> </h3>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    
    <?php
    $args = array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => 'DESC', 
    'category' => $category->term_id, );
    ?>
    
        <?php   } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```